# Generating a random sentence in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following input which contains Aircraft and Services

```
AirCrafts={'Cargo Aircraft':'1','International Aircraft':'2','Domestic Aircraft':'3'}
    Services={
        'AirCrafts':[1,2,3],
    
    'Cargo  Aircraft':[
        
        "Fedx","DHFL","Emirates SkyCargo","Qatar Airways Cargo","Cathay Pacific Cargo"    
    ],
    'International Aircraft':[
        "Air India","Air France","BA"
    ],
    
    'Domestic Aircraft':[
        "TruJet","Indigo","AirAsia"
    ]
}
```

I have a generated sentence the following sentence using SenGen Function.

```
def SenGen(alpha,beta):
    for keys,values in alpha.items():
        for key,value in beta.items():
            if key in keys:
                if values == []:
                    print(f"{keys}  are not found.")
                if len(values) > 1:
                    print(f"{keys}  are ", end="\n")
                for i, val in enumerate(values):
                    if len(values) == 1:
                        if "Not found" in value:
                            print(f"{keys} are {val}. ", end="\n")
                        else:
                            print(f"{keys} is {val}. ", end = "\n")
                    
                    else:
                        if i == len(values)-1:
                            print(f"•{val}. ", end="\n")
                        elif i == len(value)-2:
                            print(f"•{val} ", end="\n")
                        else:
                            print(f"•{val}, ", end="\n")
```

My generated output is below after running `SenGen(Services,AirCrafts)`.

```
SenGen(Services,AirCrafts)
International Aircraft  are 
•Air India, 
•Air France, 
•BA. 
Domestic Aircraft  are 
•TruJet, 
•Indigo, 
•AirAsia.
```

In the above output, I have international Aircraft are and Domestic Aircraft are.
in place of International Aircraft, I want to generate a proper sentence such that my output must look like

> International Aircrafts that run from the various airport of India are

for the Domestic Aircrafts

> Domestic Aircraft which run in within  India are

How can I generate a proper sentence as shown above?

Comment: can you please add a section that outlines what your desired output should look like. I understand that you want to have a return statement. Based on the output, we can figure out what how you want the return to look like.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you need to plug in the additional text. Otherwise the program will not know that you want these texts added.

```
if len(values) > 1:
    if "International" in keys:
        print(f"{keys}  that run from the various airports of India are ", end="\n")
    elif "Domestic" in keys:
        print(f"{keys}  which run in within India are ", end="\n")
    else:
        print(f"{keys}  are ", end="\n")
```

**Here's the code that provides you a return statement.**

```
def SenGen(alpha,beta):

    temp = '' #store the results for each iteration of `AirCrafts`

    for keys,values in alpha.items():

        if keys == 'International Aircraft':

            temp += '\n' + keys + ' that run from the various airports of India are :\n' + ',\n'.join(beta[keys])

        elif keys == 'Domestic Aircraft':

            temp += '\n' + keys + ' which run within India are :\n' + ',\n'.join(beta[keys])

        elif keys == 'Cargo Aircraft':

            temp += '\n' + keys + ' are :\n' + ',\n'.join(beta[keys])

        else:

            temp += '\n' + keys + ' are not found'

        temp += '\n'

    return temp

x = SenGen(AirCrafts,Services)

print (x)
```

If you don't want the results to be printed separately on each line, you can remove the `\n` from the string.

**Output for your reference:**

```
>>> print (x)

Cargo Aircraft are :
Fedx,
DHFL,
Emirates SkyCargo,
Qatar Airways Cargo,
Cathay Pacific Cargo

International Aircraft that run from the various airports of India are :
Air India,
Air France,
BA

Domestic Aircraft which run within India are :
TruJet,
Indigo,
AirAsia

>>> x
'\nCargo Aircraft are :\nFedx,\nDHFL,\nEmirates SkyCargo,\nQatar Airways Cargo,\nCathay Pacific Cargo\n\nInternational Aircraft that run from the various airports of India are :\nAir India,\nAir France,\nBA\n\nDomestic Aircraft which run within India are :\nTruJet,\nIndigo,\nAirAsia\n'
>>>
```

Comment: how do I write a return statement? . in place of  print(f"{keys}  that run from the various airports of India are ", end="\n"), if i return I'm getting the following error.
.
 File "<ipython-input-347-2459ecd2e6d0>", line 13

  return(f"{keys}  that run from the various airports of India are ", end="\n")
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You are running a for loop. Are you planning to send a list after you have completed your loop or are you planning to send just one set as soon as you find them? In other words, do you want your return to be a string or a list?

Comment: i want to be return has string

Comment: Check the new answer and see if this is what you were looking for. If it meets your needs, you can mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

So basically this is the line which needed change as per your requirement

```
if len(values) > 1:
   print(f"{keys} are ", end="\n")
```

You can change it to this, and you will be good to go:

```
if len(values) > 1:
  # for international the statement is different
  if keys == "International Aircraft": 
    print(f"{keys} that run from the various airport of India are ", end="\n")
  elif keys == "Domestic Aircraft":
    print(f"{keys}  which run in within India are", end="\n")
  else:
    # your else print
```

**Additional Information**

To `return` the statement, do not do like this, you need to use [String Concatenation](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-concatenate-strings?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034364&utm_targetid=dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9062011&gclid=EAIaIQobChMImf2U_e-P6wIV1KqWCh0v_QSEEAAYASAAEgKr0_D_BwE). So in order to do the return, do this in place of print

```
if len(values) > 1:
  # for international the statement is different
  if keys == "International Aircraft": 
    return str(keys) + " that run from the various airport of India are \n"  
  elif keys == "Domestic Aircraft":
    return str(keys) +  " which run in within India are \n"
  else:
    # your else print
```

Comment: how do I write a return statement? . in place of  print(f"{keys}  that run from the various airports of India are ", end="\n"), if i return I'm getting the following error.
.
                                                       
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yes your return cannot cannot have the `print` statement. You can use concatenation @kkkreddi  See **Additional Information** section in my answer

Comment: @kkkreddi did you try the changes which I have suggested you for `returning` a statement?

Comment: my Desired output shud look like International Aircraft  that run from the various airport of India are
•Air India, 
•Air France, 
•BA. 
Domestic Aircraft which run in within India are  
•TruJet, 
•Indigo, 
•AirAsia.  this should come from the return statement

Comment: Should look like @kkkreddi ?

Comment: this is  output 'International Aircraft that run from the various airport of India are \n'
from additional information

Comment: Try this and tell me if that works out for you @kkkreddi ```return str(keys) + " that run from the various airport of India are" + "\n"```